# Consulta selectRaw con varios campos

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8

Buenos días compañeros.

Actualmente realizo las siguiente consultas para calcular el total de clientes tanto potenciales ($clientsusersp) como fidelizados (clientsusersf). Mi consulta es la siguiente: ¿Puede unificar estas dos consultas en una sola para optimizar el código?

```
$clientsusersp = DB::table('users')
                ->selectRaw('users.*, clients.user_id, count(*) as cuentap')
                ->join('clients', 'users.id', '=', 'clients.user_id')
                ->where('loyalcustomer', '=', 0)
                ->groupBy('users.id')
                ->get();

$clientsusersf = DB::table('users')
            ->selectRaw('users.*, clients.user_id, count(*) as cuentaf')
            ->join('clients', 'users.id', '=', 'clients.user_id')
            ->where('loyalcustomer', '=', 1)
            ->groupBy('users.id')
            ->get();
```

Gracias a todos de antemano.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar una sentencia case para *contar* los clientes potenciales y los fidelizados en dos campos separados en una sola consulta, que en este caso no tendrá cláusula `where`, pues los queremos todos y los vamos a ir *contando* por separado:

```
$clientsuserspf = DB::table('users')
                ->selectRaw('users.*, clients.user_id, count(case when loyalcustomer = 0 then 1 end) as cuentap, count(case when loyalcustomer = 1 then 1 end) as cuentaf')
                ->join('clients', 'users.id', '=', 'clients.user_id')
                ->groupBy('users.id')
                ->get();
```

No estoy seguro de cómo laravel traduce los campos que incluyes a mysql, pero *siento* que hay campos de más en la consulta, o de menos en el `group by`. Si no necesitas toda la información de los usuarios, sugiero que la cambies por:

```
$clientsuserspf = DB::table('users')
                ->selectRaw('users.id, count(case when loyalcustomer = 0 then 1 end) as cuentap, count(case when loyalcustomer = 1 then 1 end) as cuentaf')
                ->join('clients', 'users.id', '=', 'clients.user_id')
                ->groupBy('users.id')
                ->get();
```

Que tiene una traducción directa a SQL válido y claro.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la aclaració Jachguate, es lo que necesitaba para optimizar la consulta. Un saludo.

Comment: Un gusto ser de ayuda :)